# Hidden characterictics of idex file causing failure

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create an index of machine names to loop through. The file looks right but fails to loop through machines at all as if there is hidden characters or something about the file that is unusual. What am I missing? Thanks - yeah I'm a newbie.

PowerShell:

```powershell
$uncServer="\\*******\DHCP"
$username="*****"
$password="*******"
net use $uncServer $password /USER:$username
$input_path=$uncServer+"\"+'winsexport.txt'
$output_file='D:\Projects\StoreControls\machinfo\allworkstations.txt'
$regex='\b[S]\d{6}\b'
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern "ACTIVE" |Select-Object Line | `
    Select-String -Pattern $regex -Allmatches|%{$_.Matches}|%{$_.Value}| get-unique >       $output_file
net use $uncServer /delete
```

eg. output

```powershell
s123420
s123421
.
.
```

loop logic:

```powershell
FOR /F %%i IN (d:***********\allworkstations.txt) DO (    #this does nothing
    start /B d:\***********\GetMachInfo.bat %%i
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
         )
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to speculate what knowing what's inside *winsexport.txt* file. The most likely culprit is CR or LF character so try and remove these. Change

```
 ... -Allmatches|%{$_.Matches}|%{$_.Value}| get-unique ...
```

to

```
 ... -Allmatches|%{$_.Matches}|%{$_.Value -replace "`r|`n|\s|`t",""}| get-unique ...
```

Why do you switch back to command prompt loop? You could carry on in powershell

```
foreach($machine in (gc d:***********\allworkstations.txt)){
    d:\***********\GetMachInfo.bat $machine
    sleep 1
}
sleep 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this all a try - a work in progress.  I'm converting to Powershell as I can.

Comment: Well, this did not work.  It's what I was aiming for so it's a big help, however, the extracted data is from a WINS server and I wonder if that introduces something weird at the file or character level.  I can create another file, same name, and similar data and my scripts loop through the machines fine. I'll try the "full" PowerShell script above but I doubt it will work either.  It's frustrating to have the data look correct but not work.

Comment: well, show us what your data looks like and i'm sure we can work it out

Comment: snippet of input data - RUTH1          [20h]  DYNAMIC  ACTIVE     463058f   UNIQUE          5/12/2014 4:50:24 AM  172.16.130.70   172.16.41.12 

 S443402        [00h]  DYNAMIC  ACTIVE     46298b0   MULTIHOMED      5/9/2014 6:44:47 PM  172.16.177.2    172.16.41.12 

 S443402        [03h]  DYNAMIC  ACTIVE     46298b1   MULTIHOMED      5/9/2014 6:44:38 PM  172.16.177.2    172.16.41.12 

 S443403        [20h]  DYNAMIC  ACTIVE     45d2a11   UNIQUE          5/11/2014 2:11:12 AM  172.16.177.8    172.16.41.12

Comment: nothing suspicious in your output..try my amended answer, removes tabs and white spaces too. are all the names you extract in the same format, ie letter _S_ followed by seven digits?